# Restrict page if Auth::user()->id != user_id using middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware, restrict

i use middleware to restrict the admin page from non-admins, and i can restrict pages with a list of "patients" from other users by using a policy, but if i use a policy. I have to repeat the code can() method in every function. If i use middleware to check if the user_id in the url == Auth::user()->id. I do not need to repeat this, but how do i get the user_id from the url in my middleware?

**the route**

Route::get('/patients/{patient}', 'PatientController@edit')

*What i have now*

**PatientPolicy**

```
public function view(User $user, Patient $patient)
    {
        // does this patient belong to user
        return $user->id == $patient->user_id;
    }
```

**PatientController**

```
public function edit(Patient $patient)
    {
        // authenticate logged in user
        $user = auth()->user();

        // can the loged in user do this?(policy)
        if($user->can('update', $patient)){
            return view('patient.edit-patient', compact('patient', 'user'));
        }
        return view('403');
    }
```

*what i should have in a middleware*

**UserMiddleware**

```
/**
 * @param $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == User::patients()->user_id) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

Does somebody know how to check if the {patient} in the routes user_id == the logged in user()->id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `Illuminate\Http\Request` object injected into `handle` function in middleware this is pretty straight forward to get patient id from url:

```
/**
 * @param $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $patientId = $request->patient; // patient id from url!

    $patient = Patient::find($patientId);

    if (!$patient) {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'Patient not found!']);
    }

    if (Auth::check() && (int) Auth::user()->id === (int) $patient->id) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: O YEAH! This helped me alot, but i did need to tweak it a little bit. Because find gets a list of al the patients, but i only need to restrict the page of 1 patient that doesn't belong to that user. So i wil post how i fixed it thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Leorent,

Your answer helped me alot and this is how it got fixed

**Route**

Route::get('/patients/{patient}', 'PatientController@show')->middleware('user');

**UserMiddeware**

```
public static function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $patientId = $request->patient->user_id; // user_id from patient in url!

        if (Auth::check() && (int) Auth::user()->id == $patientId) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('403');
        }
    }
```

Thanks again!